# Strange workflow in WSO2 application publisher

Tags: wso2

I have three roles in EMM. They are admin, developer, and user. The developer should be able to submit applications for review in the APP Publisher and the admin should approve such submitted. After that, developer will publish the app and let the user download it in the APP Store.

However, everything works fine but the APP Publisher allows the developer to approve the app by itself.

I can provide the EMM role permission. There is on Create, Delete, Install, Publish and Update. Using this, I can grant the Publish permission to the developer. It can do all: submit for review, approve and publish together. If I don't, developer can't even submit the application for review.

Is there any way to do what I want?

Comment: No one has idea or feel strange with this workflow??